# Convert encoding function Python35

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding

I'm porting a Django application from Python27 to Python35. 
I used 2to3 in order to automated the code translation, but I'm in trouble with a function that converts a string in a specified encoding. 
The function is the following:

```
def convert_encoding(text, source_encoding=None, destination_encoding='utf-8'):    
    if not isinstance(text, unicode):
        try:
            text = unicode(text, encoding=source_encoding, errors='ignore')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as exc:
            # write log
            pass

    try:
        text = text.encode(encoding=destination_encoding, errors='ignore')
    except Exception as exc:
        # write log
        pass

    return text
```

More in detail, this function is used when I need to compare db values to some strings. 
The db tables are encoded in `Latin-1`, but I should convert the string in UTF-8.

I know that in Python3 all strings are Unicode, so based on what I have understood, I should remove the following piece of code from my function:

```
if not isinstance(text, unicode):
    try:
        text = unicode(text, encoding=source_encoding, errors='ignore')
    except UnicodeDecodeError as exc:
        # write log
        pass
```

The problem is raised for example in a unit test that inserts in database (latin-1) via sql file this string '°C'.

After the insert, the unit test compare the value from database (I see this character as 'Â°C') to a Python string ('°C') calling the `convert_encoding` function with the following parameters:

```
source_encoding='latin-1', destination_encoding='utf-8'
```

What I expect is that the db string 'Â°C' is converted to '°C', but instead the db string changes to b'\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0C'. 
I checked the python documentation about encoding function, and I found out that it returns a bytes object. 
So I tried to convert it in this way

```
bytes.decode(b'\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0C', 'utf-8')
```

but the result is 'Â°C' again.

I'm a little bit confused about this, I don't understand what i'm missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should stop doing any manual encoding or decoding.

Configure your MySQL connection to use Unicode mode with UTF-8 encoding:

```
charset='utf8',
use_unicode=True
```

This means that all results will be returned as unicode strs. You will not have to decode it.

The connection encoding is separate to the table/database encoding. MySQL and the MySQL driver will transparently decode the table encoding, encode to UTF-8, then decode to unicode str.

Remove all `unicode()`, `encode()`, and `decode()` statements from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes you are right, but unfortunately I can't modify database configuration

Comment: No, no. Change the database connection settings in Python

Comment: @Giordano Why can't you change the database connection settings within Python?

Comment: Sorry for the late, anyway, i can modify the database connection within python and I tried but doesn't resolve the problem. What I have tried is change the encoding, from UTF8 to Latin-1 of the sql files, and it works.